# WPF Style Template for button

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF application. I am trying to customise a button. Which I have partially achieved however I can not seem to set the background of my button to a RadialGradientBrush. I really can't see what I'm doing wrong. I also don't want any border for the button.

Below is the code I have. Where I have the value for the property background it says token is not valid?

```
<Application.Resources>
 <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="brushSecurityButtRadial">
        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.3"/>
    </RadialGradientBrush>

<!-- style for button -->
    <Style x:Key="buttSecurity" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,2,1,2"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="brushSecurityButtRadial"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">                    
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="GBP / USD" Style="{StaticResource txtSecurity}"/>
                        <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Source="C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Country Flags\ICO\GBP.ico"/>
                        <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Source="C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Country Flags\ICO\USD.ico"/>
                    </Grid>               
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: do you have vs2012? use blend

Comment: -1. You shouldn't change your question after users have provided you with an answer. You have two users that correctly answered your initial question, but you didn't mark either of them as correct. If users see you doing that, you could find that they'll avoid answering your questions in the future. In fact, you didn't even change the text in your question (don't do that now), so your question asks one thing and your accepted answer does not even attempt to answer that question... if I were you, I'd accept one of the original answers that actually answers the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant set the background because you have a binding error which you should see in an output window or while using snoop.
you can also use Blend to set the `GradientBrush` automatically

```
 <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource brushSecurityButtRadial}"/>
```

Comment: ah that's stupid of me. It now runs but the colour of the button is not blue or white?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Value="{StaticResource brushSecurityButtRadial}"
```

Comment: Ah that was stupid of me. It now runs but the button's back is neither blue or white?

Answer (score 1):

The template you give to the button hides its background.

Put the background to the Grid in the template.